# creating load balancer in AWS

Tags: ansible, amazon-elb, ansible-2.x

i want to create a new load balancer and assign a ec2 instances in aws using ansible . so , i created new_elb.yml file to create new elb and below is my code for ELB:

```
---
  #tasks:
- name: creating load balancer
  #local_action:
  ec2_elb_lb:
    name: "apache-balancer"
    state: present
    zones:
      - us-west-2a
      - us-west-2b
    listeners:
      - protocol: http
        load_balancer_port: 80
        instance_port: 443
~
```

i am getting the error as follows:

```
ERROR! 'ec2_elb_lb' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/final_elb.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  #tasks:
- name: creating load balancer
  ^ here
```

can anyone please tell what is correct way to declare ELB and register ec2 instances using ansible?

Comment: If you are using roles approach and creating top level playbooks to call this role. Then the code should work. Just make sure "local_action" is not present.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a [playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks.html).  A playbook is essentially a list of "do these things on these servers".  However, what you've given it is just an action.

The structure you need is more like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: creating load balancer
      ec2_elb_lb:
        <snip>
```

The bare list of actions you have is what you'd put in a `tasks/main.yaml` file in a [role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles).